# JSONata array to array manipulation with mapping

Tags: jsonata

I need to transform array to array with some extra logic:

1. Map field `name` in array if it exists in the mapping object, if not process it as it is in the source
2. Sum up values of objects with the same name
3. Remove objects with zero value

for example here is the **source** json:

```
{
  "additive": [
      {
        "name": "field-1",
        "volume": "10"
      },
      {
        "name": "field-2",
        "volume": "10"
      },
      {
        "name": "field-3",
        "volume": "0"
      },
      {
        "name": "field-4",
        "volume": "5"
      }
    ]
}
```

object with **mapping** config(`field-1` and `field-2` is mapped to the same value):

```
{
  "field-1": "field-1-mapped",
  "field-2": "field-1-mapped",
  "field-3": "field-3-mapped"
}
```

and this is the **result** that I need to have

```
{
  "chemicals": [
    {
      "name": "field-1-mapped",
      "value": 20 
    },
    {
      "name": "field-4",
      "value": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

as you can see `field-1` and `field-2` is mapped to `field-1-mapped`  so the values are summed up, `field-3`  has 0 value so it is removed and `field-4` is passed as it is because it's missing in the mapping.

so my question is: is it possible to make it with JSONata?

I have tried to make it work but I stuck with this lookup function that doesn't return default value when name is missing in mapping:

```
{
"chemicals":  additive @ $additive #$.{
                    "name": $res := $lookup({
                          "field-1": "field-1-mapped",
                          "field-2": "field-1-mapped",
                          "field-3": "field-3-mapped"
                    }, $additive.name)[ $res ? $res : $additive.name],
                    "amount": $number($additive.volume),
                } [amount>0] 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easiest to break it down into steps as follows:

```
(
    /* define lookup table */
    $table := {
        "field-1": "field-1-mapped",
        "field-2": "field-1-mapped",
        "field-3": "field-3-mapped"
    };

    /* substitute the name; if it's not in the table, just use the name */
    $mapped := additive.{
        "name": [$lookup($table, name), name][0],
        "volume": $number(volume)
    };

    /* group by name, and aggregate the volumes */
    $grouped := $mapped[volume > 0]{name: $sum(volume)};
    
    /* convert back to array */
    {
        "chemicals": $each($grouped, function($v, $n) {{
            "name": $n,
            "volume": $v
        }})
    }
)
```

See https://try.jsonata.org/0BWeRcRoZ